# Send Request to browser from server (Java EE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee, servlets, struts

I want to send a request (or any response or notification) from the server side to the browser without a browser request to the server.

I use JSP and the Struts framework in my Java EE application. When some one is on my page, and when some processing in done in my action class/servlets, I want to send a notification or message or request to the browser to be appeared on the page. Here the relevant page cannot be refreshed or reloaded and it may be handled on the browser side with javascript or jquery. I use Http.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: Example: The application is an online inventory system. An Admin has logged in. If one of the items is out of stock, the admin should be notified saying that that particular item is out of stock without the admin searching the stores and do nothing (when he is on his account page, a pop up may be displayed to him).

Comment: Let's think this through...how would you expect this to work? How would you be able to target a specific browser from your server?

Comment: @lan: Thanks for  your reply. How would some social media sites do in chat boxes ? can't we store the last request came for a perticular user session and send back another response again back?

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure what you meant but according to my understanding you can do this.I guess [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) is the thing you are looking for.Comet is the technique where in server pushes the data to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Pushlet** concept which might address your requirement
http://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-2000/jw-03-pushlet.html